# Alacritty Cargo installation error: crossfont no binary and error: attributes are not yet allowed on `if` expressions

Tags: rust-cargo, alacritty

When installing the alacritty terminal on debian with cargo I get this error:
[image: attributes are not yet allowed on if expressions]

And when running `cargo install crossfont` I get this error:
[image: crossfont no binary]

Please help. Oh yeah btw I am running debian just so you know.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Alright boys i got the solution:

You need to install [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) and update to the newest version
then just run it again and it works magically